# tint2: add "systemmenu" to panel

Tags: openbox, application, panel, launcher, fbpanel

I am trying to customize `tint2` panel using the `tint2 settings` (panel configurator). This is how it looks at the moment:

[image]

I can add application icons to the launcher, etc. But I cannot find how to add "system menu" to the panel. By "system menu" I mean what I think in windows is called "Start button", ie where you click on it and have your applications in categories, such as "Office", "Utilities", "Internet", "Audio & Video".

I have been using fbpanel until now, and there is this thing called "systemmenu". This is how its configured in `fbpanel`:

```
Plugin {
    type = menu
    config {
        IconSize = 22
        image = /usr/share/pixmaps/debian-logo.png
        systemmenu {
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how it looks like:

[image]

when I click the Debian swirl icon, the "system menu" opens, and I can see all my applications.

In `tint2` I can only add individual icons on the launcher. But that is not practical for all icons. I don't understand how anybody could use panel without the systems menu. I cannot add 50 individual icons. I need a menu where I can see and select from my applications.

**Is it possible to add systems menu to the panel ?**

I have created an issue on the projects [gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/o9000/tint2/-/issues/772), but got no reaction:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tint2, I added a button to open the Openbox root menu as follows.

1. In Openbox the configuration file ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml, I added the following lines to map the Openbox root-menu to open with the keypress of the Super+Escape keys (used below).
2. In the Openbox menu select Reconfigure to reload the rc.xml file.
3. Go into Tint2 Settings
4. Edit current theme
5. Go to Panel Items and add Button to panel.  Place it where you prefer.
6. A new tab is added to Tint2 Settings. Click on Button 1.
7. I added 'Menu' text and a tooltip.
8. Then I entered for the Left Click command, xdotool key Super+Escape, to send the Super+Escape key combination to Openbox.  xdotool needs to be installed.
9. I changed the button's background and font color to be more visible.